# How to pass a data of 'div' tag to python

Tags: html, forms

I'm trying to send a value of `<div>` tag.

`<div>value here</div>`
I want to send the value to server when submit button's clicked.

How can I send it without using any form type tag.

Or is there any form option that makes its shape doesn't look like a form?

for example, twitter bootstrap has a few button options.
`<button class='btn btn-link'>` 
the button looks like text link with this option.

Comment: A form is invisible, you can style any element however you like with CSS, what troubles are you having exactly?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that form tags have 'hidden' type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a 'hidden' option on form type tags.

Here's the example.

`<input type="hidden">`